Issue with RocksDB growth in Solana private cluster despite low transaction volume
Good afternoon everyone,
We recently started our Solana cluster for a project where we require hiding some transaction data and disabling commissions. However, we encountered a significant issue with RocksDB growing to over 1 terabyte in just 1-2 weeks, despite having almost zero transactions in the cluster during this time. We've tried various optimization techniques, including adjusting flags in the genesis validator script and limiting transactions per second (TPS), but the problem persists.
Genesis Validator Script:
#!/usr/bin/bash

file_latest_slot="/home/sol/latest_optimistic_slot"
file_latest_hash="/home/sol/latest_optimistic_hash"

# Check for the presence of latest slot and hash files
if [ -s "$file_latest_slot" ] && [ -s "$file_latest_hash" ];
then
    # Path 1: Latest Slot and Hash found
    SLOT_X=$(cat "$file_latest_slot")
    HASH_X=$(cat "$file_latest_hash")

    # Purge slots after the latest snapshot to manage ledger size
    solana-ledger-tool purge -l /var/solana/ledger/ "$SLOT_X"
    
    # Deleting latest slot and hash files
    rm "$file_latest_slot" "$file_latest_hash"

    solana-validator \
        --wait-for-supermajority "$SLOT_X" \
        --expected-bank-hash "$HASH_X" \
        --require-tower \
        --ledger /var/solana/ledger \
        --accounts /var/solana/accounts/ramdisk \
        --rpc-port 8899 \
        --identity /home/sol/config/validator-keypair.json \
        --vote-account /home/sol/config/vote-account-keypair.json \
        --rpc-faucet-address 127.0.0.1:9900 \
        --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
        --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage \
        --init-complete-file /home/sol/init-completed \
        --no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader \
        --no-poh-speed-test \
        --no-os-network-limits-test \
        --limit-ledger-size \
        --full-rpc-api \
        --gossip-port 8001 \
        --gossip-host n0.test.com \
        --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
        --log /home/sol/logs/solana-validator.log \
        --log-messages-bytes-limit 10000000 \
        --allow-private-addr \
        --rpc-threads 2  
else
    # Path 2: Starting without latest slot and hash
    [ -e "$file_latest_slot" ] && rm "$file_latest_slot"
    [ -e "$file_latest_hash" ] && rm "$file_latest_hash"
    
    # Normal startup path with TPS reduction measures
    solana-validator \
        --require-tower \
        --ledger /var/solana/ledger \
        --accounts /var/solana/accounts/ramdisk \
        --rpc-port 8899 \
        --identity /home/sol/config/validator-keypair.json \
        --vote-account /home/sol/config/vote-account-keypair.json \
        --rpc-faucet-address 127.0.0.1:9900 \
        --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
        --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage \
        --init-complete-file /home/sol/init-completed \
        --no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader \
        --no-poh-speed-test \
        --no-os-network-limits-test \
        --limit-ledger-size \
        --full-rpc-api \
        --gossip-port 8001 \
        --gossip-host n0.test.com \
        --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
        --log /home/sol/logs/solana-validator.log \
        --log-messages-bytes-limit 10000000 \
        --allow-private-addr \
        --rpc-threads 2 
fi

Issue:
Despite our efforts, RocksDB continues to grow rapidly even when the cluster experiences minimal transaction activity. We've considered implementing snapshotting and resetting the cluster when the ledger size reaches certain limits, but we're unsure if this would effectively address the problem.
Any suggestions or solutions for optimizing RocksDB growth in our Solana private cluster would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance.


However, we encountered a significant issue with RocksDB growing to over 1 terabyte in just 1-2 weeks, despite having almost zero transactions in the cluster during this time. We've tried various optimization techniques, including adjusting flags in the genesis validator script and limiting transactions per second (TPS), but the problem persists.

The first sentence mentioned having almost zero transactions in the cluster, whereas the second sentence mentions limiting TPS.

Was your node previously running "unbounded" in regards to TPS, and you then attempted to limit it ? Also, your script mentions with TPS reduction measures but I'm not sure how any of the flags below would reduce TPS ... can you elaborate ?
How many nodes are in your cluster ? Note that at the very least, your cluster will have vote transactions from every voting participant.

Your nodes appear to have the RPC API enabled. For a basic sanity check, it would be good to confirm the output of the following two methods. Knowing the total tx count and the block height will give us an approximate tx's / block:

getTransactionCount
getBlockHeight

Next, I think the following 3 arguments are of interest:
        --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
        --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage \
        --log-messages-bytes-limit 10000000 \

The first two are fairly standard RPC arguments, and will result in extra disk footprint. The last argument is saying that you're allowing 10 MB of log message bytes per tx. It probably depends on the program whether there are 10 MB of logs to be written, but I think you can probably see that this could get very large very fast.
Lastly, I think the value for --limit-ledger-size may be of interest. The node will not purge old data until it exceeds this number of shreds present in the Blockstore. You can search your logs for instances of alive shreds in slots to find out many shreds are in your Blockstore.


The first sentence mentioned having almost zero transactions in the cluster, whereas the second sentence mentions limiting TPS.

Yes, because even when our cluster is not being used, it generates transactions (we suspected this is because solana is proof-of-history), so we decided that since it generates a bunch of probably empty transactions, if we limit the number of transactions, the cluster will take less memory.
(I'll split the reply into several massages because there's a character limit here)


Was your node previously running "unbounded" in regards to TPS, and you then attempted to limit it? Also, your script mentions with TPS reduction measures but I'm not sure how any of the flags below would reduce TPS... can you elaborate?

I just found on the internet that these flags would help me limit TPS, but yeah, we didn't have limits before and everything worked as standard. But again, we thought we'd test this to reduce the amount of memory it consumes per day.


How many nodes are in your cluster ? Note that at the very least, your cluster will have vote transactions from every voting participant.

Only two, one is the genesis (you've seen its config), and the validator.
And about transaction count and block height:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getTransactionCount"}
'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":3646217,"id":1}
and height:
d '
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,
"method":"getBlockHeight"
}
'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":3647426,"id":1}
and thanks for advice, i will try to change the --log-message-bytes-limit

Lastly, I think the value for --limit-ledger-size may be of interest. The node will not purge old data until it exceeds this number of shreds present in the Blockstore. You can search your logs for instances of alive shreds in slots to find out many shreds are in your Blockstore. I can't find anything about that in the logs, so here's the logs: pastebin.com/QFfQiN2y

"it generates transactions (we suspected this is because solana is proof-of-history"
==> Proof of history generates ticks which represent the hashes that PoH performed. This does occupy some blockstore space (shreds)

"to reduce the amount of memory it consumes per day"
==> Not to nitpick, but I believe you're conflating disk space and memory (RAM)

"3646217 for transaction count / 3647426 for block height"
==> Hmm, so about 1 tx / block. This isn't that many and assuming both of your nodes are participating, this sounds roughly right for votes only and no "user" transactions

"I can't find anything about that in the logs"
==> The link you provided has 10 lines of log output, you need to search the entire log

"Not to nitpick, but I believe you're conflating disk space and memory (RAM)" ==> No, I'm not arguing that I could be wrong, but as I understand it, it's precisely these ticks for PoH that consume so much memory over time. The blockchain maintains the history of all this, but how do we deal with it and clean up these ticks, if possible? As you've already noticed, we have 0 user transactions, but nevertheless, every day rocksDB takes up more and more memory from the disk.

"The link you provided has 10 lines of log output, you need to search the entire log" ==> sorry, here about shreds: https://pastebin.com/PYgzR1jk

thank you so much for trying to help <3
